# Suppressing form post on enter when a textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, webforms, jquery-events

I am using MVC, not that this makes a difference, but I have a text box for searching.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
            <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
            <div id="search_box">
            <span id="search-title">Search Site</span>
                <div>
                    <%= Html.TextBox("searchText", "type here, then press enter", new { @class = "search_input" })  %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
```

I used to have the `onblur` and `onfocus` events set on this text box to do some text swapping when the user clicked into it or out of it without typing anything.  But, I moved them into a JS file because eventually, we want to add other functionality through JS, such as autocomplete, etc.

The problem with my JS is that it submits no matter what.

```
var searchHandler = function() {

    var searchBox = "searchText";
    var defaultText = "type here, then press enter";

    var attachEvents = function() {

        $("#" + searchBox).focus(function() {
        if (this.value == defaultText) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            if (this.value == '') {
                this.value = defaultText;
            }
        }).keyup(function(event) {
            var searchTerms = $("#" + searchBox).val();
            if (event.keyCode == 13 && searchTerms == '') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });

    };

    return {

    init: function() {
            $("#" + searchBox).val(defaultText)
            attachEvents();
        }
    }
} ();

$().ready(function() {
    searchHandler.init();
});
```

What I really need is to just make it so that enter does not submit the form if the textbox is empty.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use jQuery you can simply return a false if the validation rules are not met.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
       if( $('#searchText').val() == '')
          return false;
       else
          return true; //just to be explicit, not really necessary.
    });
});
```

Or something close to that.